# An old short story about a teacher who goes to Mars to work?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, mars

A person I know is trying to find a story about a teacher who travels from Earth to Mars and starts working there.
It's old, maybe from Bradbury or Asimov.
That's the only information she gave to me.

Comment: I remember a fascinating old story about a schoolteacher who, as the tale begins, has just *returned* to Earth *after* many years of teaching kids on Mars, and she is shocked by how education back here has changed during her long absence. I don't know if this is what your friend has in mind, but if it is, it was asked about, and answered, at this link: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/44872/story-about-schooling-in-the-future-using-video-monitors-at-home/44882#44882

Comment: I remember that story, although I would have guessed at Clifford Simak. The other teachers have to keep their pupils interest; a court has ruled that the children must be on front of the screen but the parents aren't compelled to monitor which channel their children are watching. A female teacher keeps the boys' interest by offering the possibility that her halter might slip; a male teacher, I think, does silly tricks by balancing a chalk on his nose. The protagonist of this story starts out by describing what her life was like back on Mars and makes her lessons interesting.

Comment: Yeah! That's the story! Thanks to everyone who helped and sorry for my English  I'm not a native speaker! I will also ask about that Simak story